How can I access a system-wide package from a Python Poetry environment?
I'm trying to get my Python project going on a Raspberry Pi. Currently, I want to capture an image on the camera and apparently picamera2 is the way to go. I installed the package via sudo apt install -y python3-picamera2 as recommended here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/tree/main
However, as I'm within a Python Poetry virtual environment, I'm not able to access system-wide packages (like this one). I also tried to install the package in the virtual environment, but I also failed (poetry add picamera2 doesn't work).
When switching to a pyenv environment, I can access picamera2. How can I get access from with my poetry environment?

virtualenvs.options.system-site-packages
